# Shimano integrated shifter/brake, model ST-2200

Tags: shimano, brifters

The question I am asking is on the Shimano ST-2200 (Claris) shifter brakes. Are the actual levers made of plastic?

Comment: If they are plastic, it's almost certainly glass-fibre reinforced and may well be both stronger and lighter than an equivalent metal part. Plastic doesn't have to mean low-quality.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, plastic. All the levers on all the ST-2x00 STIs are plastic.

Answer (score 0):

The ST-2500 has metal brake levers. Looking at photos, it appears the ST-2200 uses the same metal levers.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  This contradicts the other answer, so you should provide some evidence for this.

Comment: Yes, some additional evidence would make this answer more than an assumption.